# Scroll Panel Using Custom ScrollBar Fail

Tags: vb.net, scrollbar, space

I'm trying to scroll a panel using some custom vertical scrollbars controls, but I'm always failing since when the main horizontal scrollbar of panel reach the maximum value, there is still space to scroll to the others two.

The problem, as I see is because of the thumb height of the panel's scrollbar, but I can't fix this.

Please help me. Here is an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Nfn7.png